# Как через python отключить устройство от USB

Tags: python, usb

*Хочу отключить телефон от компьютера подключённого к USB зная его ID оборудования, такое возможно сделать? К примеру через какую-то простенькую библиотеку для роботы с USB портами.*

Хочу сделать это через python

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на библиотеку [PyUSB](https://habr.com/ru/post/430528/), возможно подойдет для решения Вашей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Лишь одними средствами `Python'a` это будет очень тяжело сделать(или вообще не возможно). Нашёл вот **[такой](https://github.com/iamgyz/usbEjector/blob/master/usb_eject.py)** модуль. Он извлекает флеш-накопители с помощью `powershell'a` . Для `*nix'совых` систем можно использовать bash.

**[ТУТ](https://poweruser.guru/questions/1323787/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-usb-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-powersh)** пример нашёл(для powershell'a).